# How to handle keypress of default button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I thought I'd handle not clicking on my default button (which is on my asp.net master page) by checking if enter was pressed and handling it.  Basically when users were on any input type fields and they hit enter, it would actually execute the event of my default button on my form (as mentioned it is a button on my master page that allows for a global search).

So users were like hey wait a minute i hit the enter key on an input field why am I suddenly on a search results page....I dont blame them...

I thought I'd handle it with this:

```
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Which the problem no longer happened, and I was happy...until I found out all my buttons on for instance my jquery dialog no longer executed when you tabbed to them and hit the enter key...Well I see the reason why because I'm returning false.  But how should I structure this so this does not happen if you are focused in on a for example asp.net button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only on handle textboxes

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

*As per comment, Can I add this in my site.master page but ignore one specific text box*

Excluding a textfield

```
$('input[type=text]').not('.search').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here I have include a [**demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/wX4sk/), In last textbox (search) event is not associated.

Use Event Delegation Approach

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[type=text]:not(.search)', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert('Enter pressed')
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/wX4sk/1/)

Comment: But I feel like adding this to all my pages isnt the way to go.  Can I add this in my site.master page but ignore one specific text box, namely a textbox with controlid = search?  The reason being is my master page contains this textbox `#search` to do global searches, so I want to exclude this textbox but not any other textbox.

Comment: @JonH, Yes that can be acheived. I would suggest you to add dummy css class name lets say `search` instead of using control id

Comment: @JonH, I have updated the answer, Just use this code in master file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind even to exact element on page:

```
$('.aspNetButton').on('keypress', (function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```